# Use R as a restful service

Tags: json, r, hbase, shiny, opencpu

Currently I have a `shiny` web app that can do some calculations on a 3GB data.frame loaded in memory.

Now instead of implementing this feature on `shiny` web app, I need to make it a restful service that pipelines its calculation to another app in `JSON` format, so that people can use it by sending http request with url like http://my-app.com/function

I'm trying `opencpu` right now, but I don't quite understand how can I load and keep the large data in memory so that I can use api of `opencpu` to call functions in package just to do calculations, not to load the large data from disk every time I send http request.

One workaround might be to use `hbase` as in memory database and use `rhbase` to load the data. But before I invest time in learning it I want to know if it is a reasonable choice for 3GB data.frame since it might add more overhead in serialization and other stuff that offset its speed benefit.

What would be a better way to implement this functionality? Solutions using packages other than `opencpu` are also welcome, and it's better to be free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at [Plumber](https://github.com/trestletech/plumber).  You decorate your R functions with comment code (that can include you loading data) and it makes it available via a REST API.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your data in a package and add this package to `preload` in the server config.